# how does the python min function works

Tags: python

I was reading the question where the desired output was to get the element with minimum value

so if

```
d= {'a':2,'b':3,'f':5}
```

The answer is a

The answer given is `min(d, key=d.get)`

can anyone explain how this works

Comment: Find the `key` of `d` where the function `d.get(key)` (equivalent to `d[key]`) returns the lowest comparable value.

Comment: @eumiro , min function also works if do `min(d.values())` i am not getting what is the second arument used for. i mean how is the second argument related to first argument

Comment: [The documentation is very good.](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) "The optional *key* argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for `list.sort()`."

Comment: @user2082226 - `min(d.values())` returns `2` and you cannot obtain its corresponding key `a` directly from it. `min(d, key=d.get)` returns the key `a`. So decide whether you need `a` or `2`.

Comment: @eumiro  can't the `min(d)` work??

Comment: @user2082226 `min(d)` returns the minimum key, not the key with the minimum value

Comment: @user2082226 - `min(d)` returns `a` in your case, because `a<b<f`, not because `2<3<5`. For `d={'a':3,'b':2,'c':1}`, `min(d)` returns `a`, but `min(d, key=d.get)` returns `c` (because `1<2<3`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `min` function returns the minimum value of an iterable according to the given key. In this case it returns the key of `d` with the minimum value. `d.get` allows you to access the corresponding value to the dictionary key, which are iterated over when you iterate over `d`.

For example:

```
>>> min([3, 5, 2, 1, 5])
1
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> for i in d:
...     print i
b
c
a
>>> d.get('b')
2
>>> d.get('d')  # Nothing is returned
>>> min(d, key=d.get)
'a'
```

The `key` argument to the `min` specifies what key you want to find the minimum on.

For example:

```
>>> min(['243', '172344', '6'])
172344
>>> min(['243', '172344', '6'], key=len)
6
```

The `min` function does something like this:

```
>>> min(['243', '172344', '6'], key=len)
# sort the list with key (call `len` on every element and sort based on that)
# sorted(['243', '172344', '6'], key=len)
# return the first element (lowest value)
# sorted(['243', '172344', '6'], key=len)[0]
6
```

Comment: how did `i in d`  work. isn't the d is dictionary , i thought we have to use d.iteritems() for that

Comment: @user2082226 iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys - it's directly equivalent to `for i in d.keys()`

Comment: i am not getting this. so `d` is the dict thats ok . now what is the function of `key=d.get` i understand the d.get() gets the value stored at some key , but from where it gets its key

Comment: @user2082226 the `min` function calls `key` to sort the iterable, and it returns the first element of the resulting list. The sorting method calls the function on each element of the iterable to sort them. This is just like how the `map` and `filter` function `key` arguments work.

Comment: why min need `key` to sort. can you explain with code what happens during the call. you mean that `min` function needs the `key` so that it can get the values stored at that key so value becomes d.get(key). so after all the values are fe5tched , it then sorts them in ascending order and gives the first one oin the list. am i right??? so `key=d.get` is tranlated to `d.get(key)` for evry item to get the value there

Comment: I find both the question and this answer quite useful from an educational point of view, and not only. Thanks.