# Getting an AttributeError using min funciont in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, function, error-handling, min

### Source Code

```
data[data['current_balance'] == ['current_balance'].min()]
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-7c38f54b69b2> in <module>
      1 #observation with minimum current balance
----> 2 data[data['current_balance'] == ['current_balance'].min()]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'
```

Comment: `min` isn't a method of a list object.  You can do `min(['current_balance'])` -- that will at least be syntactically valid, although I don't think it will get you the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `min()` on list `['current_balance']`, your code should be like this:

```
data[data['current_balance'] == min(data['current_balance'])]
OR
data[data['current_balance'] == data['current_balance'].min()]
```

I don't know what type of object `data['current_balance']` holds. But one of the above will eliminate the error you are getting.

> EDIT here some link for further informations:

**Guides**

- [w3schools.com | min function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_min.asp)
- [geeksforgeeks.org  | max() and min() in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-min-python/)

**Stack Overflow**

- [how does the python min function works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14976081/13903942)